# Утечка памяти. Язык Си

Tags: c

Начал изучать Си и столкнулся с проблемой. Надеюсь, на изображении видно, я аллоцирую память для перемеенной str. Дальше пробую присвоить строку "a". Вывожу str на экран. Затем освобождаю память. И у меня два вопроса:

1. Почему valgrind говорит, что было два аллока? (я думаю, это связано с printf, но как именно, понятия не имею)
2. Какова причина утечки 5ти байт в поле definitely lost?

Забыл сказать, что весь текс программы, что выше находится, является полностью закомментированным.

Премного благодарен

[image: на картинке изображён результат исполнения программы]

Comment: Забыл сказать, что весь текс программы, что выше находится, является полностью закомментированным.

Comment: В строке `str = "a"` вы присваиваете указатель на другую строку, находящуюся где-то в неизменяемой памяти, и тем самым безвозвратно теряете доступ к выделенной malloc'ом памяти. Операция `free(str)` становится недопустимой, потому что с неизменяемой памятью нельзя что-либо делать.

Comment: И да, текст программы должен быть текстом, а не картинкой. Или вы предлагаете нам вручную перепечатывать все буквы с вашего скриншота, чтобы воспроизвести проблему?

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! Насчёт картинки я понял

Comment: *"Дальше пробую присвоить строку "a"*... В языке С невозможно "присвоить строку". Строка - это массив. В языке С не поддерживается присваивание голых массивов. Скопировать данные в голый массив можно только вручную поэлементно или библиотечной функцией. Но не присваиванием. Ваше `str = "a"` делает совсем не то, что вы думаете.

Comment: всем большое спасибо. как много ещё можно изучить! класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обратится к элементам выделенной памяти необходимо использовать оператор разыменовывания(*), в вашем случае вы просто присваеваете указателю строку, находящуюся где-то в памяти, в следствии чего теряете указатель на аллоцированную память, и происходит утечка памяти.